# Getting word-topic probabilities with mallet

Tags: terminal, mallet

I am using mallet through the terminal. I have imported the training data in a single file format:

```
project5 TokenNameCOMMENT This is the actual text
```

and I have used the train-topics command to create topic models of several sizes.

What I want to do now is to test the trained models on a test set of the same format. 
More specifically I want, if possible, to get the topic assigned to each of my test files, along with the probability of each word for that topic and test file. If it is possible to get the probability of each word for any topic as well that would be great.

Thank you